# How can I use manipulate on multiple lists within a function?

Tags: programming, physics, simulation

So I have my N-Body Problem set up like so, and I can plot it in ListPointPlot3D, but I cannot figure out how to stick this into a manipulate function.

```
Clear["Global`"];
Off[General::spell, General::spell1, General::infy];
\[Delta]t = 0.05;
Particles = 3;
n = 1000;
l = n/10;
CreateParticle[size_] := Module[
  {posrand := RandomReal[{-4.00, 4.00}],
   velrand := RandomReal[{-10^-13, 10^-13}]},
  {{posrand, posrand, posrand},
   {velrand, velrand, velrand}}]

Data = Map[CreateParticle, Range[Particles]];
Positions = Table[Data[[n, 1]], {n, 1, Length[Data]}];
Velocities = Table[Data[[n, 2]], {n, 1, Length[Data]}];
AngularMomentum = 
  Table[Positions[[i]]\[Cross]Velocities[[i]], {i, 1, 
    Length[Data]}];

Forces[particle_] := Sum[If[particle != others,
    ((1)/(Norm[
         Positions[[others]] - Positions[[particle]]])^3)*(Positions[[
        others]] - Positions[[particle]]), 0],
   {others, Length[Data]}];
Force := Map[Forces, Range[Particles]];

Clear[Orbit1, Orbit, Orbits];
Orbit1 = Table[0, {i, n}, {j, Particles}];
Do[{
   If[j < l,
    {Velocities[[i]] = 
      Velocities[[i]] + Force[[i]]*\[Delta]t + AngularMomentum[[i]]/
       Norm[Positions[[i]]]},
    {Velocities[[i]] = Velocities[[i]] + Force[[i]]*\[Delta]t}],
   Positions[[i]] = Positions[[i]] + Velocities[[i]]*\[Delta]t,
   AngularMomentum[[i]] = Positions[[i]]\[Cross]Velocities[[i]],
   Orbit1[[j, i]] = Positions[[i]]
   }, {i, 1, Particles}, {j, 1, n}];

Orbit[t_] := Table[Orbit1[[i, t]], {i, 1, n}];
ListPointPlot3D[Orbits = Map[Orbit, Range[Particles]]]
```

The code works, but not exactly the way I want it to. Which I am trying to fix myself (but any pointers would be appreciated). My main question though is how to manipulate time for my plot?

Comment: What value do you want to manipulate?

Comment: I would like to manipulate time. I have n steps of dt.

Comment: Can you help with this?

Comment: Sorry I had a look but I couldn't wrap my head around how your orbits were stored in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out on my own, If you define the "Orbits" array before the plotting, it works like so:

```
Orbits = Map[Orbit, Range[Particles]
Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[Table[Orbits[[i, j]], {i, 1, Particles}]], {j, 1, n, 
  1}]
```

If you add this to the end of my code, it works just fine. Also, if anyone is using the above code, you should redefine the "Forces" function and "Force" array within the loop. For some reason it doesn't work if you don't. Also switch the direction of the force. I have it wrong above.